# QDoubleValidator пропускает запятые, не пропускает точки

Tags: qt, валидация

`QDoubleValidator` допускает использование лишь запятой, как разделителя дробной и целой части. Считываемое далее с лайнэдита число соответственно не воспринимается как `double`. Как заменить запятую на точку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод validate у класса `QValidator` виртуальный. Почему бы этим не воспользоваться для расширения возможностей `QDoubleValidator`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDoubleValidator>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

class CustomValiudator : public QDoubleValidator{
    QStringList _decimalPoints;
public:
    CustomValiudator(){
        _decimalPoints.append(".");
        _decimalPoints.append(",");
        _decimalPoints.append("comma");
    }
    State validate(QString &str, int &pos) const{
        QString s(str);

        for(QStringList::ConstIterator point = _decimalPoints.begin(); point != _decimalPoints.end(); ++point){
            s.replace(*point, locale().decimalPoint());
        }
        return QDoubleValidator::validate(s, pos);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    CustomValiudator v;
    QString str("123");
    int pos = 0;

    qDebug() << v.validate(str, pos); //2 -> QValidator::Acceptable

    str = "123.4";
    qDebug() << v.validate(str, pos); //2 -> QValidator::Acceptable

    str = "123comma4";
    qDebug() << v.validate(str, pos); //2 -> QValidator::Acceptable
    return a.exec();
}
```

Суть в том, что все разделители, которые нам нужны мы заменяем тем разделителем, который устраивает `QDoubleValidator`.

Comment: спасибо. сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но как можно посмотреть код функции validate, определенной для класса QDoubleValidator? Ведь вы же сначала посмотрели как она написана для него, чтобы переопределить для CustomValiudator, если я всё правильно понимаю

Comment: @bronstein87, нет я обошелся справкой. Если очень хочется посмотреть код, я пользуюсь дебаггером. Исходник валидатора у меня оказался в `C:\Qt\4.8.6\src\gui\widgets\qvalidator.cpp`

Answer (score 5):

Можно задать для валидатора английскую локаль, в которой разделителем является точка

```
QLocale locale(QLocale::Englishs);
validator->setLocale(locale);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так.

```
lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[-]{0,1}\d{0,}\.\d{0,}"),0) );
```

Comment: я ведь вроде бы про QDoubleValidator спросил, задавать валидаторы регулярными выражениями я умею

Comment: Тогда смело используйте регулярное выражение.

Comment: ну это то всё понятно. в таком случае, вы хотите сказать, что невозможно заменить разделитель в QDoubleValidator на точку?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нет.

Comment: просто я к чему спросил, мне необходимо так же задавать диапазон возможных значений, и метод setRange, принадлежащий QDoubleValidator как нельзя лучше для этого подходит, а как задавать диапазоны регулярными выражениями я не знаю.